# Why can't I create a 3 channel histogram with this image?

Tags: python, image, histogram, opencv

I'm trying to basically take an image and create a 3 channel histogram of an image. I've been told I can use this syntax:
(where bin_size is 8 or 16, and imgp is just the path to the image.)
Is there a better way to do this, or to combine 3 histograms into one?

```
image = cv2.imread(imgp)
x = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2], None, [bin_size], [0, 256])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/hist_image_index.py", line 68, in <module>
    hist_index_img('hist_test/car_test/img01.png', 'rgb')
  File "D:/hist_image_index.py", line 25, in hist_index_img
    x = cv2.calcHist([image], ([0, 1, 2]), None, [bin_size], [0, 256])
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:1202: error: (-215:Assertion failed) csz == 0 || csz == dims in function 'cv::calcHist'
```

Comment: Looks like image wasn’t loaded properly.

Comment: well, i opened the picture to make sure it loaded and the image did show up. so thats not the problem. What i mean is i did cv2.imshow(image)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate histogram of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590051/how-to-calculate-histogram-of-an-image)